# Настройка форматирования стилей в WebStorm с помощью stylelint

Tags: webstorm

Интересно узнать, в проекте есть список правил в файле .stylelintrc , webstorm на них реагирует и подсказывает где неправильно, но при форматировании горячими клавишами ctrl+alt+L происходит линтинг по правилам самого webstorm. Можно как-нибудь настроить этот дефолтный линтинг и чтобы он брал правила из .stylelintrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В 2021.1 будет добавлена возможность запускать `stylelint --fix` из редактора, см. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25069#focus=Comments-27-4707153.0-0.

Возможности импортировать настройки форматирования из `.stylelintrc` пока нет, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-31347](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31347)

Answer (score 0):

В VSCode в settings.json можно добавить

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
},
```

И при каждом сохранении (ctrl + S), стили будут "стайлинтиться". В webstorm такого не нашел.